# how to set VS2010 settings considering utf8 so i could send data to mysql database as they are

Tags: c#, mysql, utf-8

I have MYSQL database that has a table that(character set is on utf8->utf8_general_ci). when i insert string data in this table(via MYSQLquery browser) Central European "ČĆŽŠĐ" letters are correctly inserted. But, when i try to insert the same via C# application(simple VS2010 windows form application) for:

**"Č"** i get **"C"** in table, **"Ć"** i get **"C"** in table and for **"Đ"** i get **"D"**.
**"Ž"** and **"Š"** are good.

i suppose that its up to VS2010 options, or ...

any idea why this is happening?

### Code

On Click event I send data to my table:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a= textBox1.Text;
    string b= textBox2.Text;
    int b= int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
    string d= textBox4.Text;

    string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=root;password=xxx;database=table";
    string myquerystring = "INSERT INTO table VALUES(0,'" +a+ "', '" +b+ "','"+c+"', '"+d+"')";

    try
    {
        conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = myquerystring;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

OK,

I tried this Encoding logic:

```
        string letters = "čćžšđ"; 

        byte[] byteENC = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(letters);

        Console.WriteLine("UTF-8  Text : {0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteENC));
```

and I get them as they are. Also, i get the same result when I do this in win form app (result in mbox is correct).

But, when i transfer this same string to database **ČĆĐ** are **CCD**.

Something happens in transfer. What? I need help?

Comment: Can u put here som e of your C# code ?

Comment: Look Peter, the code is really simple kind of one. You have connection string, query string, few texboxes and btns on a form, ..., nothing serious. And connection works great but I just don't get data into database as i write them in textBox and send them to database.

 For example, if I write "Č" into textBox in database I see "Č", but if I write "Ž" in textBox and send it to my database table I see this letter as I wrote him.

and thats teh mess

Comment: @Sylca - While the code may be simple, it is helpful to see it, especially to see how you are applying encoding to the strings that hold your data.

Comment: you are right @Chris :-), code will come right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to modify your connection string to add charsetOption to this>>>

```
string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=root;password=xxx;database=table;CharSet=UTF8";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to convert string Encoding

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
string n = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
MessageBox.Show(n);
```

---

**EDIT**: Or you can get central europe encoding

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
byte[] data = enc.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change table collation to utf8_unicode_ci because i think in your collation is Accents removed because  š equals s and so on ... and all downcase letters are UPPERCASSED ...try change collation

Comment: heyyyyy, I've got "Đ" now as it should be!!! we are getting closer to the solution!

Comment: You are welcome...but what about š č ť and so on ? still is converted to s c t ...?

Comment: I have idea ...if you are use central europe charset in winform app set the collation to central europe collation> 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-ce-sets.html

Comment: "š and ž" are ok. but still nothing with "č and ć", they are still converted to "c and c". and yes, letters muts be uppercased (đ must be uppercased "Đ" for right insert into db )for this proposition of you. still trying, ...

Comment: And you can try add CharSet=UTF8; to your connection string> 
string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=root;password=xxx;database=table;CharSet=UTF8";

Comment: I'm trying this now: **Specifying a Character Set for C#**. It says: The DllImportAttributeCharSet field identifies the underlying character set as ANSI or Unicode. The character set controls how string arguments to a method should be marshaled. Use one of the following forms to indicate the character set:

Comment: This: [DllImport("dllname", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
[DllImport("dllname", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
[DllImport("dllname", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]

Comment: got it Peter, it was **string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=root;password=xxx;database=table;charset=utf8";**  I was going through my code and there was a extra connection string (remain of my attempts)  with different setup. I erased it and it works great. Post it again so I could take it as an answer!!! Thank you man